# Django - Simple redirect to requested URL

Tags: python, django, url, redirect

I'd like to do that, but this

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
```

yields a redirect loop. I suspect it's because the request object is the website you're **on** at that time.

Whole function

```
def permit(request, pk):
    if int(request.user.id) == int(pk):
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    else:
        return render_to_response('forbidden.html')
```

The user has clicked a link on a webpage. pk is the regx search term in urls.py. I want this to redirect to the page the user clicked on if the user is authorized, not the page he is currently on.

Comment: Well, yes. Why are you trying to do this? Where do you actually want to be redirected to?

Comment: Is this for logging in redirect purposes?

Comment: The user has clicked a link. I think I need to include the whole function. It's in the original post.

Comment: This still makes no sense. If the URL is mapping to the `permit` view, you will always go to that view, again and again. I don't understand how you expect anything different to happen.

Comment: Of course, how silly of me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as soon as the user is "redirected", the function `permit` is called. The if statement is true (since it is the authenticated user) and the redirect happens again... To prevent this loop, only redirect, if there was a post request:

```
def permit(request, pk):
    if request.POST:
        if  int(request.user.id) == int(pk):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
        else:
            return render_to_response('forbidden.html')
    ## Return your login page here.
```

Comment: Thanks, that was my misunderstanding. But now I get the error " The view notendur.views.permit didn't return an HttpResponse object.
 "

Comment: That is because you are not returning any view, you will still have to have your default logic below. See my edit above. You should have some default login for all users. But it seems like your logic is a bit odd. I would suggest you rather have a view to handle the login request and then a view to handle the user once logged in. In the "looged in view" redirect unauthenticated users to the login view.

Comment: I have those, I think. Ok thanks to your explanations the code now works, mostly. What is missing is that the URL I want him to go to first (the one he clicked on) does not seem to happen.